# Need help unittesting rust library that has calls to execve

Tags: rust

**Background:**

I'm currently writing unittests for a library that is capable of starting other binaries, guaranteeing the binary will die after a timeout on linux.
The unittest is currently done by calling a binary that would normally sleep for 10 seconds and then create a file containing some data. The binary should be killed before those 10 seconds meaning the file should not exist had the timeout functioned. The path to that binary is currently hardcoded which is not what I want.

**What I need help with:**

Problem is I want to have access to such a binary when the crate is compiled, and then pass its path to the library being tested (thus being able to call said binary using execve syscall without hardcoding its location allowing other users of my crate to compile it). This means I need to somehow have a binary generated or grabbed during compilation and somehow have access to its path inside my unittest. Is there any decent approach to doing this?

The code for the binary can be written in whatever language as long as it works. But preferably rust or C/C++. Worst case it can be precompiled but I'd like to have it compiled on the fly so it works on ARM or other architectures aswell

**What have I tried:**

The current method is to simply hardcode the binary path and compile it manually using G++. This is not optimal however since if anyone downloads my crate from crates.io they won't have that binary and thus cannot pass its unittests.
I have been messing around with [cc](https://docs.rs/cc/latest/cc/) in [build.rs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#build-scripts), generating C++ code and then compiling it, but CC appears to be for compiling libraries which is not what I want since it attempts to link the binaries with the library (I believe thats what it's doing), and I have been googling for a few hours without finding any approach to solve this problem.

Comment: Change to `execvpe` and instruct the users to set their `PATH` environment variable to where their binary lives and call it by its non-directory-qualified name only?

Comment: Other options: instead of hardcoding, get the absolute path from a config file?

Comment: Those are definetly options I'll consider :) but since others might use this crate after importing it from crates.io I'd prefer a solution which doesnt require configuration from the user just to pass some unittests